# format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char*’, but argument 2 has type ‘char**’

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following code trying to use pointers to store a value requested to the user:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

char *p_texto = "Prueba Raul";
char *p_texto2;

int main(){
    
    printf("Escriba un texto\n");
    scanf("%c", &p_texto2);
    while(*p_texto2!='\0'){
       printf("%c", *p_texto2);
       p_texto2++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char*’, but argument 2 has type ‘char**’
```

How can I fix that and avoid to use `char p_texto2[200]`?

Comment: That is `C`, not `C++`

Comment: Do you know what the format `%c` does in `scanf` (and similarily in `printf`)?

Comment: `%c` tells `scanf()` to ASSUME the corresponding argument is of type `char *` which causes undefined behaviour (your compiler might be diagnosing that for you, but is NOT actually required to) in your code because it passes something else.  `p_texto2` is of type `char *`, so `&p_texto2` is of type `char **`.   One way to fix that is to change the type of `p_texto2` from `char *` to `char` (i.e. remove the `*`).   That will trigger other errors in the loop though (i.e. fixing the first problem will expose other problems in your code that you haven't yet asked about).

Comment: If I define `char p_texto2`and then use %c in the `scanf` and `printf` the variable is a pointer?

Answer (score -1):

You have declared char pointer `char *p_texto2;` so, you need to pass the p_text02 to `scanf("%c", p_texto2);` because the `p_texto2` will hold the base address of string, Instead you are passing the address of pointer(`&p_texto2`) which is the address of pointer that holds the string base address. Also, the format specifier is wrong need to use `%s` to get string in C.

If you don't want to use `char p_texto2[200];` , it is not good advise to use just char pointer to hold the string base address as without assigning a size of string the run-time behaviour is undefined(data loss may occur). `malloc` can be used to allocate run-time memory.

eg:

```
int n;
printf("Enter the sizeof string...");
scanf("%d, &n"); // note: the character that can be entered is n-1 as '\0' take the last byte.
p_texto2 = malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
scanf("%[^\n]s", p_texto2);
// Other method to scan a string with spaces.
gets(p_texto2); // this is supported till c11.
fgets(p_texto2, n, stdin);
```

Comment: Your fix will stop the particular diagnostic from the compiler.   It will also cause undefined behaviour, since `p_texto2` is a null pointer.  Fixing a compilation error by introducing undefined behaviour (with any symptoms occurring at run time, with no diagnostic required from the compiler) is generally BAD advice.

Comment: Thanks @Peter for pointing out.. I have improved my answer.

Comment: @Fizn-Ahmd i tested it and the print is not working as it should. I raised another question regarding that as it only prints until it reaches the first space.

Comment: @mrc I have updated the scanf() to read string with spaces. Hers is the defination of it. ^\n tells to take input until newline doesn’t get encountered. Here we used ^ (XOR -Operator ) which gives true until both characters are different. Once the character is equal to New-line (‘\n’),  ^ (XOR Operator ) gives false to read the string.

Comment: U could use gets(p_texto2); but, it has been removed from c11. So it might give you a warning when implemented.

Comment: Instead you could use fgets(p_texto2, n, stdin);